# Django filter OR .filter(x=1,y=2) like Django Docu

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters

So this works:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Item.objects.filter(Q(creator=owner) | Q(moderated=False))
```

according to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

this should give me the same as the first code snippet

```
Item.objects.filter(creator=owner, moderated=False)
```

but it acts like:

```
 Item.objects.filter(creator=owner).filter(moderated=False)
```

Edit:
I misunderstood that the 2nd and 3rd snippet are the same unless Many-To-Many Fields come into place. But both have nothing to do with the first snippet

Comment: Can you create an [mcve]? the first snippet is an or condition which is different to the other two snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q with operator | can be translated into:

Please give me all objects of instance Item which `creator=owner` **OR** `moderated=False`

(OR is important here)

When `.filter(creator=owner, moderated=False)` says:

Please give me all objects of instace Item which `creator=owner` **AND** `moderated=False`

Comment: Thanks now i got it!